# Uniqueness of the opposite

Tags: logic

I have a doubt. I need help.

Consider the statement: "Given a real number $r$, there is a real number called the opposite of $r$, denoted by $-r$."

Well… for me we can conclude from the statement the uniqueness of the opposite of $r$, since if $s$ and $t$ are opposites of $r$, we will have:
$-r = s$ and $-r = t$

Therefore, by the axioms of equality (in particular the Law of Euclid), we will have: $s = t$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Do you have a definition of the opposite of $r$? Or at least a characterization of it?  In general simply asserting the existence of a thing does not assert its uniqueness.  I can assert that there is a number called the square root of  $9$.  That assertion is true, but the number is not unique.  Your reasoning would lead to an incorrect conclusion for the square root of $9$.

Comment: If you want to establish uniqueness, you'll need to use the characterization of the opposite of $r$.

Comment: If we write x ^ 2 = 9 and x ^ 2 = a, we would have to conclude that a = 9. Is not it?

Comment: In the question that I have proposed, I am only concerned with the logical aspect of the statement. I do not mind the opposite meaning of a real number.

Comment: No.  Following your reasoning about the opposite of $r$, one could argue that if $s$ is the square root of $9$ and $t$ is the square root of $9$, then $s=t$. Both $3$ and $-3$ count as square roots of $9$.

Comment: If you work in first-order logic with equality, you cannot simply "reverse" the [substitution axiom for functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms): $x=y \to f(x,z)=f(y,z)$. It is true that $(n+k=m+k) \to n=m$ but it is false that $(n \times 0 = m \times 0) \to n=m$. Thus, in a "formal" context, the Law of Euclid does not follows from the equality axioms; you have to prove it from arithmetical axioms.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence “Given a real number $r$, there is a real number called the opposite of $r$, denoted by $-r$” already implicitly assumes the uniqueness of the opposite, because of the presence of the word “the”.

Anyway, giving a name to a thing does not define it. It would be far more interesting to *define* what *a* opposite is and then to prove that it is unique. Such a definition might be: *an* opposite of a real number $r$ is a real number $r^\star$ such that $r+r^\star=0$.

Comment: I fully agree: in writing the opposite of r, I am already admitting the uniqueness of the opposite of r.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. No such axiom. First u should know rings.

---

A ring R is a set R equipped with two binary operations + and · satisfying the following three sets of axioms, called the ring axiom.

1.R is an abelian group under addition, meaning that:

- (a + b) + c = a + (b + c) for all a, b, c in R (+ is associative).
- a + b = b + a for all a, b in R (+ is commutative).
- There is an element 0 in R such that a + 0 = a for all a in R (0 is the additive identity).
- For each a in R there exists −a in R such that a + (−a) = 0 (−a is the additive inverse of a).

2.R is a monoid under multiplication, meaning that:

- (a · b) · c = a · (b · c) for all a, b, c in R (· is associative).
- There is an element 1 in R such that a · 1 = a and 1 · a = a for all a in R (1 is the multiplicative identity)

3.Multiplication is distributive with respect to addition:

- a ⋅ (b + c) = (a · b) + (a · c) for all a, b, c in R (left distributivity).
- (b + c) · a = (b · a) + (c · a) for all a, b, c in R (right distributivity).

---

And the uniqueness is proved by:

If$t$ has two opposite $r_1$, $r_2$, then
$$r_1=r_1+(t+r_2)=（r_1+t）+r_2=r_2$$